# Script to continuously execute javascript function on website

Tags: javascript, php, python, onclick

A friend of mine has recently posted his javascript game online. You first go to the homepage and then you click on a button that brings you to the game.

Something like this when I inspect element:

```
onclick="playgame()"
```

When somebody clicks this, a counter increments so he knows how many people have played. He only did this for practice as he doesn't actually expect anyone to play.

I want to surprise him though, by having a script continuously click this button over and over and make him think he has 1000's of plays.
He'll love the prank when I tell him ;)

Does anyone know if this is possible?
I'm experienced in c#, but from looking online, php seems to be more suitable? I'm 100% open to any other methods
Thanks

EDIT: I was looking at something like this

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
, 'jsfunction();'
, '</script>'
;
?>
```

But then I don't know how I will execute this on his website

EDIT 2: Actually seems like python would be the correct option

Comment: dear Teemothy, please, provide the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if this work in your situation, but if you would like to do something x times, you can do it with a loop like in any other language.

For example if you would like to call a function x times, you could do it this way:

```
function someFunction(x) { console.log(x) }
var iterations = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < iterations ; i++ ) {
  someFunction(i);
}
```

Infinite

```
var iterations = 0
while(true) someFunction(iterations++)
```

Comment: Yeah I thinking of using something like an infinite loop to perform it, it's more connecting to the website and executing the function I'm having trouble with

Comment: check out the infinite thing

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple iteration, make a function like this and run it.

```
function click1k() {
    var clicks=1000;
    for (var i=clicks; i>0; i--) {
        playgame();
    }
 }
```

And run:

```
click1k();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a website you could use something like iMacros addon for firefox and just record a macro, you can even use js for more complex scripts but a simple loop would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger that button continuously. Here is the code.

```
 setInterval(function(){
    $("Selector").click();
 }, 5000);
```

It will click automatically selected button or any element every 5 seconds.
You can increase or decrease the time so it will look real to get play counter in time gaps